# Accessing list inside visual force template

Tags: visualforce, email

I have a class(batch apex) wherein i am querying(and filtering) and getting a list of records. I need to access these records inside a visual force email template by using `<apex:repeat>`. However this is the error i am getting when trying to save the template:

> Unknown property 'core.email.template.EmailTemplateComponentController

This is the template snippet :

```
<apex:repeat var="i" value="{!lstDefaulters_DeliveryTeam}">
    <td>{!i.User__r.name}</td>
    <td>{!i.Role__c}</td>
    <td>{!i.Location__c}</td>
</apex:repeat>
```

Is what i am trying to do achievable in vf email templates.

Comment: It seems that lstDefaulters_DeliveryTeam isn't reachable by your template. What is this field, list or relationship name?

Comment: @Ilya Lepesh lstDefaulters_DeliveryTeam is a list of records. The requirement is to iterate over this list inside the vf email template.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display list in Visualforce email template, you should iterate through all childred related to object from which the template retrieves merge field data.
Or you can include a [custom component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_email_templates_intro.htm) in a Visualforce email template that uses that custom controller.

Error you having after saving you snippet, describes that property doesn't exist. I think you aren't using `apex:repeat` properly.
If you related type is `relatedToType="Account"` and Child Relationship Name is `lstDefaulters_DeliveryTeam` (assume that you have object Defaulter) repeat should access list through object:

```
<apex:repeat var="i" value="{!relatedTo.lstDefaulters_DeliveryTeam}">
```

Check your relathionship name, you could miss letter `s` : e.g.`lstDefaulters_DeliveryTeams`

In case when you are using component, make sure that lstDefaulters_DeliveryTeam has public access modifier in controller:

```
private final List<Defaulter> defaulters;

public findDefaulters() {
    defaulters = [select Location__c, .. from Defaulter where ..];
}
//should be accessed by component
public List<Defaulter> getlstDefaulters_DeliveryTeam() {
    return defaulters;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I read your question right, you have a batch class that generates a list of records that you want to show in a VF email template

First principles:

- The Email Template has a relatedTo (`setWhatId(..)`) and a recipient (`setWhoId(..)`).
- Any list you generate in the VF email template has to be derivable from `relatedTo` or (less likely) `recipient`

So, you're going to need to persist the members of `lstDefaulters_DeliveryTeam` so that they are accessible from the value of `setWhatId(..)`. @IlyaLepesh gives an example.

If this isn't practical, you can abandon the template altogether and just construct your own HTML in a setHtmlBody(...) method call

Comment: As relatedTo can only be an sobject.,that means i cannot access a list created in the batch class in the vf email template?

Comment: @starhunter -- If the list created in the batch class is persisted in the database and is a child of relatedTo, then yes, the VF template can access.  Otherwise, you have to construct the `htmlBody` yourself in the batch class without resort to using the template